# Parabolic microphone set, DIY resources?

Tags: field-recordings

I am looking for a small parabola for field recording because the one I purchased is too large to be easily transported. Do you have any recommendation for a practical small one ? I also heard about some people who were building them from scratch (using bird feeder dome cover). I am interested in any DIY ressources !

Comment: How much small should it be approximately?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Michael's suggestion, I'd recommend the Wildlife Sound Recording Society (WSRS): https://www.wildlife-sound.org/

WSRS has a member's forum and I'm sure someone there would have ideas on DIY parabolas, or recommendations of small off-the-shelf models.  Members have access to the archive of newsletters and articles as well - i think this topic is likely to have come up in the past.  There is an interesting article on Parabolic Stereo in Resources > Equipment on the website.  Nice bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Macaulay Library staff recommend the Wildtronics [**Pro Mono Parabolic Microphone**](https://www.wildtronics.com/store.html#!/Pro-Mono-Parabolic-Microphone/p/23651971/category=5592558) as the best value.

Macaulay Library also has tips about how to maximize the quality of your recordings, prepare them for archive, and other topics on their [**Resources**](https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/resources/) page.