# Parabolic Microphones?

Tags: recording, microphone, equipment, field-recordings

I'm doing some field recording but we're not able to get super close to what we're looking to record. I figured a parabolic mic might be the move, but they all seem really expensive, and our budget is quite tight (£200 ish)

Do you know any good parabolic mics that aren't too expensive? Or perhaps are you located in London/ Cambridge/ Glasgow and have one we could rent from you? Happy to provide more details!

Cheers!

Comment: Related: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/parabolic-microphone-set-diy-resources?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Wildtronics have one parabolic dish kit for around 250 USD, the [Pro Mini Parabolic](https://www.wildtronics.com/store.html#!/Pro-Mini-Parabolic-Clear/p/58684090/category=16104026). They also have only the [parabolic dishes](https://www.wildtronics.com/parabolicdish.html) from between 85 and 150 USD.

Answer (score 2):

If you are super tight on budget, but keen to craft something, this could be interesting:
[A DIY low-budget NocMig parabolic microphone](https://nocmig.com/2021/12/09/guest-blog-a-diy-low-budget-nocmig-parabolic-microphone-by-franck-hollander/)

You could combine a parabolic dish from wildtronics, as suggested by Jon with some D.I.Y. microphone setup.

I just learned that the Birdmic Startnext campaign by Birdfox [here](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/birdmic/birdmic-listen-to-birds-like-never-before) didn't reach its goal. Otherwise, this could have been interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Becky, these are good for the price at £69:  https://www.parabolicmicrophone.co.uk/

ta